# How to change BaseStore from SAP Spartacus storefront

Tags: spartacus-storefront

As Spartacus is for B2C process there is no any option to change BaseStore from storefront. I have a drop down for different countries and now want to change BaseSite from it.

Answer (score 3):

So finally I made it working. I am storing baseSite to session if its changed from dropdown and if user is coming back reading it first from session.
 here what you have to do to make it working:

1. Override `BaseSite` service and change initialize method similar to the initialize method of `LanguageService`. (which check if baseStore is stored in session )
2. Listen to SET_ACTIVE_BASE_SITE action and set payload to session. (again similar like activeLanguage effect in `LanguagesEffects`)
3. Now in B2cStorefrontModule config add your other sites as

```
 B2cStorefrontModule.withConfig({
     context: {
       baseSite: ['electronics','mystore2','mystore-uk', 'mystore-canada'],
       language: ['en'],
       currency: ['USD']
     }
```

So the main solution is, you listen to basestore change action and store the value to session and on page load you read basestore from session

Comment: I assume you are switching `baseSite` at runtime, are you reloading the whole app or store after the switch?

Comment: yes. I have to reload store after switching the country, to get user permissions and new content.  This is the current solution in standard solution

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this. Check full code on [Building the Spartacus Storefront from Libraries](https://sap.github.io/cloud-commerce-spartacus-storefront-docs/building-the-spartacus-storefront-from-libraries/#adding-import-declarations-and-storefront-configuration-settings)

```html
B2cStorefrontModule.withConfig({
    backend: {
      occ: {
        baseUrl: 'https://localhost:9002',
        prefix: '/rest/v2/',
        legacy: false
      }
    },
    authentication: {
      client_id: 'mobile_android',
      client_secret: 'secret'
    },
    context: {
      baseSite: ['electronics']
    },
    i18n: {
      resources: translations,
      chunks: translationChunksConfig,
      fallbackLang: 'en'
    }
  }),
```